# How to sort by INT type column as it would be VARCHAR type column in Derby DB?

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by, derby

Here is the SQL expression:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable ORDER BY integerTypeColumn ASC;
```

Column "integerTypeColumn" is INT type. Using Berby DB the results are for example:

```
1
2
3
1000
1200
```

But I need to sort like as if the column "integerTypeColumn" would VARCHAR type. Then the results would be:

```
1
1000
1200
2
3
```

Is it possible to do it using Derby?

Comment: You can cast to varchar.

Comment: No, it will throw an error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Cannot convert types 'INTEGER' to 'VARCHAR'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [**cast**](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj33562.html) to `char`.

```
SELECT * FROM someTable 
ORDER BY CAST (integerTypeColumn AS char(10)) ASC;
```

Comment: I did so, but Derby do not allow to do that - [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj33562.html) you can see.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis: i have posted the same link. Have you noticed that i've used `char`?

Comment: Wow, super :) `CAST (integerTypeColumn AS char(10))` helped! Interesting nuances :)